# Using target_blank to open a new tab on click - can I load a new page in the original tab automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I'm running an offer and when someone clicks through my first page I'd like them to be sent to another offer page in a new tab - pretty easy with target_blank.

However, while the user is sent to the new tab, I'd like the original tab to load to another page - is this possible?

Or, if not - would it be possible to open 2 different tabs simultaneously when the user clicks through my first page? Or, a new window and a new tab?

I'd like to do this the first way I mentioned, but if that's not possible really any other way of opening two tabs/windows when the user clicks through the link on my first page would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an event listener for when the link is clicked and change the current windows location. An example with jQuery would be

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    window.location.href = "http://google.com";
});
```

Or native javascript

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location.href = "http://google.com";
});
```

Comment: Awesome - so would I just put either of these pieces of code in my header section?

Comment: Javascript is best placed at the foot of the document, after everything else in the page. But yes that is the general idea. You may want to specify an id rather than target all elements and specifying an index.

Comment: Ok cool - so if I was to add an ID to my link, (let's said "clicker") where would i specify that in the jQuery or JS code?

Comment: depends on whether you want to use jQuery or just javascript. For jQuery you would use `$('#clicker')` instead of `$('a')` and for javascript you would use `document.getElementById('clicker')` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]`

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to get this to work using an ID and couldn't, so I've used the code you provided exactly and here's what I have:

<a href="LINK" class="cta" target="_blank"><img src="img.png" alt=""  border="0"/></a>

and

<script type="text/javascript" document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location.href = "http://google.com";
});
</script>

The page loads my link in a new tab, but the original tab doesn't load to Google - any suggestions?

Comment: That code is just HTML, not the code I provided. Can you provide the full code on [http://www.pastebin.com](http://www.pastebin.com)

Comment: Here is the code to use. I suggest you read up on how to use javascript as your example code is very wrong. [https://gist.github.com/cjmarkham/9272500](https://gist.github.com/cjmarkham/9272500)

Comment: That works perfectly thank you. You were correct, what I had was very much wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the question. Use JS to open multiple pages with one click

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com'); window.open('http://www.bing.com');">One Click</a>
```

Comment: The question was about redirecting the current page not opening several windows.